# What is the best practice in this situation Async Await with try/catch or Promise.then().catch()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, try-catch, nestjs, es6-promise

I try to create a function that returns values ​​from the server, if one of the values ​​returns with an error then everything that comes back to me from the function falls and I get NULL,
If I use try / catch the problem is solved.
What is the best solution in terms of performance and something that can work in the result I want

```
public async getUserById(id: number): Promise<dto> {
  const arr = [];
  const user = await this.userService.getUserById(id);
  try {
  const company = await this.companyService.getCompanyIdToken(
    user.company_id
  );

  UsersProvider.setUserCompany(user, company);

  for (const space of user.spaces) {
    try {
      const Response = await this.companyService.getSpaceById(space);
      arr.push(Response);
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error) **// Here I expect you not to throw an error**
    }
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error) **// Here I expect you not to throw an error**
}
return user;
}
```

Comment: There is no measurable performance difference between `try`/`catch` and `.catch()` - especially not when compared to the time it takes until the error occurs asynchronously. Use whatever is clearer, more readable code.

Comment: The performance part of your question is irrelevant.  The actual asynchronous operations will dominate the performance here.  As for `.then()` vs. `await`, it's really just personal choice.  Multiple asynchronous operation in sequence will typically be less code when using `await`.  Branching between different asynchronous operations will typically be less code using `await`.  Which makes easier error handling depends upon the specific situation.

Comment: "*If I use try / catch the problem is solved.*" - logging the error doesn't solve the underlying problem that caused the error.

Comment: FYI, if this is working code and you're interested in feedback on better ways to write it, then you can post at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but make sure you following the posting rules there as you would not ask this exact same question.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, in terms of performance, there isn't really a difference between try/catch and catch.

However, in my experience, try/catch statement are much clearer for peer reviews and maintenance (for error message management), but that is just a personal preference.

Moreover, if getSpaceById() can throw synchronously, then you do have to catch that synchronous exception with try/catch if you ever wish to use the .then() statement (you will get an error if you only use.catch() instead of try/catch). You might as well use the try/catch now before getting an error.